# Mule suppress catch-exception-strategy logging

Tags: exception, logging, mule

Is there any way to suppress Mule's (3.3.1) catch-exception-strategy behavior of logging the entire stack trace for a specific instance of the component?  I don't want to do it in the log4j configuration for the class because I want unexpected exceptions to log.

I want to be able to catch an exception in a flow and decide whether to log it (and scare the heck out of the operations team) or just take corrective action and move on.  In the following, is there some way to configure the first instance to not log the stack trace?

```
<choice-exception-strategy>
    <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(my.exception.SpecificException)">
        <!-- I don't want logging on this one -->                
    </catch-exception-strategy>

    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <!-- I do want it here -->
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so for Mule 3.3.1. It should be supported in Mule 3.4.0, can you try that?

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6575

Comment: Well, disappointing!  I can't switch to 3.4.0 at the moment; the group is standardized on 3.3.1 for the moment.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nikos That issue is still open. How is it supported in 3.4+ ?

Comment: @rewolf Looks like according to the defect that the fix version is 3.8.  I'm using 3.5 now and don't see that functionality available there either.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in their latest 3.8.2 release just we need to uncheck the `logException` block which is true by default.

[image]